# Quick fix for function of type Observable

Tags: angular, observable

in my service I got this function that returns me a warning when hovering `Observable<Product[]>`

"A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value"

```
getAllProducts(id, token): Observable<Product[]> {
  this.model = 'product';
  this.http.get(this.getUrlById(id), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
  .pipe(map((products:Product[] => products))
  .subscribe((products) => this.getAllProdObserv.next(products))
}
```

Is there a quick fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are typing your function with a return type of `Observable<Product[]>`,
but there is no `return` keyword in your method.

To fix it, simply return that `Observable<T>`:

```
getAllProducts(id, token): Observable<Product[]> {
  this.model = 'product';
  return this.http.get(this.getUrlById(id), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
}
```

Or type the return value as a `Subscription`:

```
getAllProducts(id, token): Subscription {
  this.model = 'product';
  return this.http.get(this.getUrlById(id), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
  .pipe(map((products:Product[] => products))
  .subscribe((products) => this.getAllProdObserv.next(products))
}
```

From the last example, I think you could also skip the `pipe + map`. It's just an extra step that does nothing in this case:

```
.pipe(map((products:Product[] => products))
```

I would just remove that line:

```
getAllProducts(id, token): Subscription {
  this.model = 'product';
  return this.http.get(this.getUrlById(id), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
  .subscribe((products) => this.getAllProdObserv.next(products))
}
```

In general, I would return the `Observable<T>` (like in the 1st example), instead of returning a Subscription.

Comment: Yes but then i got "Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Protocol[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more"

Comment: Thank you very much :) in 4 minutes I'll accept your answer lol

Comment: Welcome! I've just added another minor thing about the pipe + map that can be skipped based on the current example that you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `return` and the Object type in the `http.get` so it matches the type it's declared as.

```
getAllProducts(id, token): Observable<Product[]> {
  this.model = 'product';
  return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.getUrlById(id), {headers: {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`}})
}
```

You can then proceed using this with `subscribe` in other class.